# Any help identifying a Focus carbon Izalco with SRAM Red?

Tags: identify-this-bike, carbon, sram, carbon-fork

Buying a bike from an online listing, and trying to find some information on it. I researched Focus's serial number formatting, but since the release of this bike it has changed, and the serial number is faded on the quality sticker.

The bike features Focus Izalco badging, with an SSPS Carbon frame, and a "Focus Carbon Race Series" badge on the seat stays. I'm having trouble finding Izalco models with SRAM Red that aren't Max, and this bike isn't badged as an Izalco Max.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to believe this particular bike hasn't had some components upgraded since the original purchase?  Maybe the SRAM Red happened after market?

Comment: What does the seller say?!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Focus Izalco from 2010.

You can find a review here: [**Focus Izalco Team Milram 2010 review**](https://www.cyclingweekly.com/reviews/road-bikes/focus-izalco-team-milram-2010):

[image]

Note that bicycle has SRAM Red.  The one difference I notice is the lack of the 3T logo on the fork.

[Bicycle Blue book has an image of the frame in those exact colors (with what looks like Ultegra 6700)](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/2010%20Focus%20Izalco%20Expert%20Ultegra%20Compact/).  It even matches the red touches on the downtube near the bottom bracket:

[image]

This scheme does not have the 3T logo on the fork and looks to be an exact match for the bike you pictured.  Those touches are probably way beyond what any counterfeiter would do.  And I doubt a faked frame would have what looks like a battery holder for electronic shifting and that cable bump on the bottom bracket.

Oh, the wheels:  I hope you're a lightweight.  20-spoke rear wheels won't last if you're not, and that is one expensive wheel for trainer-only use.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like an exact match! It the wheels were aftermarket modifications, and I'm finding pro models with SRAM red. I'm 165, so I'm hoping that's lightweight enough to get some use out of these